# UITableView / UITableViewDatasource strange behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have this strange thing happening with one of my `UIViewController`s.

it is a standard `UIViewController` which contains 3 `UITableView`s and and if you change the value inside TableView one it refreshes the data array in TableView three and calls `reloadData` on TableView 3.

My datasource for TableView 3 get the `numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`
and I return the number of rows in my array which has just increased from 1 to 2 and I return 2

but I only get called `cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` once.

Has anyone experienced this before.

I have thought of changing the TableView 3 to a `UITableViewController` and adding it as  `ChildViewController` but I cant see how this is going to make any diffrence.

Regards Christian Andersen

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show the relevant code.

Comment: did you used `tableView.tag` to differentiate between your 3 `UITableView`s. If not then you must mixing your datasource of three `UITableView`s

Comment: Please show the code which you are trying